# error C2027: use of undefined type 'Channel'

Tags: c++, types, undefined

I have two files, link.h and channel.h. The link contains two objects of type `Channel`, `src` and `dst`. The files are as follows:

```
// channel.h
class Channel {
private:
    bool marked;
    // ...

public:
    void mark(void) { marked = true; }
    void unmark(void) { marked = false; }
    bool is_marked(void) const { return marked; }
    // ...
};

// link.h
#include "channel.h"
class Channel;

class Link {
private:
    Channel *src, *dst;
public:
    void mark_src(void) { src->mark(); }
    void unmark_src(void) { src->unmark(); }
    bool is_marked_src(void) const { return src->is_marked(); }

    void mark_dst(void) { dst->mark(); }
    void unmark_dst(void) { dst->unmark(); }
    bool is_marked_dst(void) const { return dst->is_marked(); }
};
```

The compiler (VC++2008) gives an error: error C2027: use of undefined type 'Channel'. I know that this means that type 'Channel' is not known at compile time but is there a way around this so that I won't have to place both Channel and Link classes in the same .h file or all the implementations of the mark methods in the same .cpp file?

Comment: I think it's because you reused `class Channel;`in the .cpp, there must be a problem of redefinition or stuff.

Comment: If you `#include "channel.h"`, you shouldn't have to forward-declare `class Channel` - it's declaration is in the included .h file. Are you sure this is how your code looks like?

Comment: You should remove #include "channel.h" from link.h and place it in link.cpp after your #include "link.h"

Comment: Do you use any #ifdef include guards you left out here? If so, check that they're not named the same.

Comment: Every one of my include file has include guards #ifndef FILE_NAME_H    #define FILE_NAME_H #endif. What exactly do you mean by 'not named the same'; every include file has a different name.

Comment: This is not the code generating the error.  Does `channel.h` also `#include "link.h"` ?  Or any other headers?

Comment: Well, sometimes people have copy&paste errors there. If you had copied these over from one file to the other without changing the name of the guard, you would have gotten this error, too. I wouldn't have another explanation for this error without more context.

Comment: @Sebi: What you posted does not show the problem. Firstly, why do you pre-declare class `Channel` in `link.h` when you include `channel.h` in it anyway? Secondly, the symptoms point to circular header inclusion, but I don't see anything included into `channel.h`. Post all relevant code.

Comment: @Ben It does not include "link.h". It however include other files #include "port.h"
#include "misc.h"
#include "congest.h"                                                          which don not #include "link.h".

Comment: @Andrey it gives the same errors whether I include it or not.

Comment: @Sebi: What did you do? What was the problem? Post what you did in the answer and accept it. It might help someone.